# How to display json array of object in android

Tags: android

This is my `JSON`:

```
[{
    "COMPANY_NO": 3,
    "COMPANY_NAME": "Labaid Specilized Hospital",
    "TOTAL_BED": 200,
    "ACTIVE_BED": 191,
    "OCCUPIDE_BED": 159,
    "FREE_BED": 32,
    "TOTAL_ADMITION": 0,
    "TOTAL_DISCHARGE": 0,
    "TOTAL_ADMITTED": 156,
    "SECOND_BED_ADMITTED": 0,
    "TOTAL_ADMITED_BED": 156
}, {
    "COMPANY_NO": 4,
    "COMPANY_NAME": "Labaid Cardiac Annex Hospital",
    "TOTAL_BED": 33,
    "ACTIVE_BED": 33,
    "OCCUPIDE_BED": 33,
    "FREE_BED": 0,
    "TOTAL_ADMITION": 0,
    "TOTAL_DISCHARGE": 0,
    "TOTAL_ADMITTED": 29,
    "SECOND_BED_ADMITTED": 0,
    "TOTAL_ADMITED_BED": 29
}, {
    "COMPANY_NO": 2,
    "COMPANY_NAME": "Labaid Cardiac Hospital",
    "TOTAL_BED": 129,
    "ACTIVE_BED": 124,
    "OCCUPIDE_BED": 111,
    "FREE_BED": 13,
    "TOTAL_ADMITION": 0,
    "TOTAL_DISCHARGE": 0,
    "TOTAL_ADMITTED": 108,
    "SECOND_BED_ADMITTED": 0,
    "TOTAL_ADMITED_BED": 108
}]
```

I want to display it like this,

[image]

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Do some searching before posting here. You will get a ton of examples how to do these things.

Comment: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ Use this to create the model class and use retrofit for parset this json file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download and get the `JSON` as `List` with `Retrofit`
2. Pass the `List` to a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` (recommended) `Adapter`
3. Customize the Adapter

Have a look at this tutorial

http://www.pratikbutani.com/2016/05/android-tutorial-json-parsing-using-retrofit-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create cards which consist these type of labels and textview there are other methods but i prefer cards more than any other and try to check this tutorials [fetch data using volley](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

Overall your JSON data is Array of objects type . You should get the first json array and then find the length of array, which is the number of objects. Finally you should iterate upto the size of array and for each object to get the values of keys inside it use  getString(KEY_NAME) function .